# How to play mp3 in WPF Without using MediaElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, mp3, media, mediaelement

I Want to play a song in the background of my WPF Application, but i prefer not using 
MediaElement Because it requires MediaPlayer 10 to run, and i can't have control on whether the user will have it or not.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use `MediaElement`, you can use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) to [play an MP3](http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3).

Comment: NAudio is for .Net. Its originally made in .Net 2 I believe. The example was made in WinForms so you know its pretty old

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to play a Mp3 File in .Net. Try [IrrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) for example which is free for non-comercial usage.
You could also [use the C# port of JavaLayer](http://robburke.net/mle/mp3sharp/).